# Office 365 for Mac: Execute VBA macro on table change

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm currently running Excel for Mac using the Office 365 subscription. I'm trying to execute a VBA macro whenever a certain cell value changes. I've already looked online and saw many code examples using the `Worksheet_Change` Sub, but it does not work for me however. This is how my code currently looks like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    Target.Font.ColorIndex = 5 
End Sub
```

I'm trying to run it on the second of four sheets. I clicked `View Code` on the second sheet so I am in the correct sheet though.

Does somebody know why it does/might not work? Does it not work in Excel for Mac?

If you need more information please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you changed the value in the cell.  It won't fire if the cell just **recalculates** a new value.

Comment: I clicked into it and typed something into it. Does this count as recalculation as well?

Comment: If you actually typed something new in the cell (even if it was a new formula), it should have fired.  So maybe it **is** a function that doesn't work on a Mac - I'm afraid I'm not sure of what limitations the Mac version has.  (To debug, you could try placing a `MsgBox "running"` in the event code to see if it is actually firing.  And, if it isn't, you should check that you haven't accidentally disabled events at some stage, so enter `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate Window, and then try again.  After that, I'm out of ideas.)

Comment: Yup, I'll already stumbled on the enable events solution but the above is actually my only code in my module. The MsgBox does not work aswell sadly, I can even put a syntax error into the sub routine and excel won't show an error. I'll try it out on windows next. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Excel for Mac seems to be just a big heap of trouble. Most of the goodies that make Excel great don't work on a Mac. Maybe you can install Parallels and then run Excel for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar trouble earlier, and because your symptoms sound like mine (code not even executing) I suspect your code is actually not on the correct sheet. The VBA window in Mac is much less detailed than in Windows and I find it confusing.

Make sure that in the left-hand pane you click on the appropriate drop down

```
VBAProject(WorkbookName) -> Microsoft Excel Objects -> Sheet2
```

and insert the Worksheet_Change function there.

Also, if you want the color to change for only a certain range, you'll need to use Intersect:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:Z99")

    'This part executes only if the cell being changed is in KeyCells
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Target.Font.ColorIndex = 5 

    End If

End Sub
```