# Excel doesn't run events (MacOS & Windows collaboration problem)

Tags: excel, vba, macos, debugging, events

Would please reputable community give some advices 'cos I'm sik&tired

When I create XLSM with Worksheet_Deactivate & Worksheet_SelectionChange on my Mac (Catalina) in Office 365 -- it works perfect. It also works on my partner's machine (Win11).
But after file's been saved from Windows and I run it on MacBook **events don't run** (no compilation errors no any messages and button-fired Sub run well)

- **the only way I've found** is: Save win-touched xlsm as new_name.xlsx and then manually recreate all VB modules, copy-paste code and save new_name.xlsm from Mac (it works again on both workstations)

I've investigated stack**overflow** and tons of other resources [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623189/office-365-for-mac-execute-vba-macro-on-table-change) [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765380/cell-change-not-triggering-vba-macro) but no such problem and no solution.

My question is -- **How to diagnose, how to catch the malfunction point?** in case MS Office keep silent. Many thanks to your karma!

Comment: So check out what Windows is doing to the file since the error occurs AFTER saving withy Windows... permissions perhaps?

Comment: Thank @SolarMike for the idea, I've checked the file permissions and changed it as owner and set FullDiskAccess to Excel but id doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless during this search I've noticed that event-handlers of one Sheet still works. Key difference of this sheet that it's been created on another workstation an it has no local characters in it's Name.
So, after changing "`CodeName`" of each sheet with event handlers within ASCII characters it works fine (see green on the picture)
[Example of local an ASCII sheet-module names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDC40.png)

P.S. and `ThisWorkbook` name also if you have event handler in it.